# Was "Back To the Future" the breakthrough of mainstream Time-Travelling science fiction in Hollywood?

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future

Recently, a remake of this movie was made in the language of Hindi and the TV reports (in Hindi) said what can be translated in English as: "*Back to the future* was the movie to introduce/define/re-define Science Fiction/Time-Travelling in Hollywood".

Did *Back to the Future* really have such an important role in bringing science fiction and time travel to mainstream audiences?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking. Are you questioning whether the original _Back to the Future_ movie was meant to present a depiction of time travel in movies alternate to what had been shown previously?

Comment: The text you quote is just marketing-speak. It doesn't actually mean anything when examined closely, so it can't be said to be true or false.

Comment: @Xantec I mean to ask, was this movie the first time travel movie in hollywood? or was it that it introduced some very new and unique concept in hollywood science fiction movies? or did this movie cause a lot of people to start watching science fiction? or Was this movie the first movie to actually make many people aware of the existence of a genre called "science fiction"? Or any thing big like that?

Comment: @MikeScott I do think the same as you, that why this question, did this movie actually caused some chance in science fiction genre in hollywood?

Comment: I've taken a stab at editing it to (hopefully) clarify what you are looking for.  Feel free to edit it further, or, if I am completely off-track, roll it back to before my edit.

Comment: @Beofett Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Is there a subtitled version of the Hindi remake somewhere?

Comment: @Raskolnikov The Subtitle file is here: http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitleserve/sub/4196960

Comment: @Raskolnikov The name of the Hindi Version is "Action Replay", you must search and download the movie from some torrent, megaupload...i am not able to find any good link for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Time travel was portrayed in quite a few productions well before the movie "Back To The Future".

For example, time travel using various methods, some with time travel paradoxes and some without, takes place in several of the original Star Trek TV series.

However, since you are specifically interested in movies, then the answer is still no. The movie adaptation of H.G. Wells [The Time Machine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054387/) came out in 1960.

(thank you, Beofett)

Comment: I am asking, "in hollywood" and not "tv" or "comic books".

Comment: The original Star Trek series was produced by Desilu Productions "co-owned by husband and wife Desi Arnaz and Lucille Ball". Can you get any more Hollywood than that?

Comment: To me more specific, was BTTF, the first science fiction/time travel "movie" (and not "tv series") that was shown in cinema teaters and was hollywood which made it big in any way?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar No.  The 1960 adaptation of H.G. Well's *[The Time Machine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054387/)* was well before BTTF.

Comment: I should also point out that even *The Terminator* pre-dated *Back to the Future*. As did *Time After Time* and *Time Bandits*.

Comment: [The Final Countdown] (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080736) from 1980 features time travel

Comment: The Philidelphia Experiment one year earlier also featured time travel prominently.